# Is OTSU thresholding for Landsat image possible using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python

I want to run OTSU thresholding to select a threshold value for a MNDWI water index image derived from Landsat image. Is it possible to run OTSU thresholding in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible with **opencv** python module. In this tutorial about [Image Thresholding](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html), it is used **Otsu’s Binarization**. So, I installed **opencv** python module (for python 3.7.3) and produced an image equivalent to **noisy2.png** (because original was reported as [missing](https://answers.opencv.org/question/72388/where-to-get-simplejpg/) for this tutorial) for being used in following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/noisy2.png',0)

# global thresholding
ret1,th1 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Otsu's thresholding
ret2,th2 = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Otsu's thresholding after Gaussian filtering
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
ret3,th3 = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# plot all the images and their histograms
images = [img, 0, th1,
          img, 0, th2,
          blur, 0, th3]
titles = ['Original Noisy Image','Histogram','Global Thresholding (v=127)',
          'Original Noisy Image','Histogram',"Otsu's Thresholding",
          'Gaussian filtered Image','Histogram',"Otsu's Thresholding"]

for i in range(3):
    plt.subplot(3,3,i*3+1),plt.imshow(images[i*3],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i*3]), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(3,3,i*3+2),plt.hist(images[i*3].ravel(),256)
    plt.title(titles[i*3+1]), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(3,3,i*3+3),plt.imshow(images[i*3+2],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i*3+2]), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

After running above code in Python Console of QGIS 3, it can be observed **OTSU's thresholding** for original image and Gaussian filtered image.

[image]

So, you can adapt above code for running **OTSU's thresholding** to select a threshold value for a MNDWI water index image derived from Landsat image. However, it can be pointed out that this approach it can be perfectly used with whatever python interpreter different of Python Console of QGIS.