# Applying Otsu thresholding method to raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, digital-image-processing, image-classification, otsu

How can I apply Otsu’s threshold method to a Raster in QGIS for reduction of a gray level image to a binary image?

[image]

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333107/is-otsu-thresholding-for-landsat-image-possible-using-qgis

Comment: Upon Research, simpler workflow is possible in ArcGIS. Add Raster to ArcMap. Navigation: Windows > Image Analysis. Select Raster in Image Analysis Menu. Under Processing > Add function. Right click on Raster > Insert function > Binary Thresholding function Link: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/editing-functions-on-a-raster-dataset.htm

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can install and use the OpenCV module in QGIS python environment (https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html).

It will require some coding but the above link will help.
In ArcGIS getting the desired result is difficult to achieve as lots of customization is required.

Comment: Yes. You can run the code in the Python Console of QGIS 3. This post might help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/355217/using-opencv-function-in-pyqgis-module-not-found